# Remove method in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, copy, remove-method

I have the following code:

```py
tree = {'nodes':[1,2,3],'root':[1]}
nodes = tree['nodes']
nodes.remove(2)
print(tree['nodes'])
print(nodes)
```

The output is the following:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
```

My question may be stupid but I do not understand why `remove` method caused that `tree` variable has changed too?

I thought that when I create a new variable like `nodes` in the example above, then any method applied on this variable will affect only this variable.

From this example, I can conclude that it had an impact on a `tree` variable too.

Is it related to the global and local variables somehow?

Comment: Let's change the terminology. You don't create a new variable `nodes`, you just attach another label `nodes` to `tree['nodes']`.

Answer (score 6):

Both `nodes` and `tree['nodes']` are referring to the same block of memory. It means they are same.
By changing any of them, both will be affected.

To avoid this, you can use `copy`.

```
from copy import copy

nodes = copy(tree['nodes'])
```

In this case, they are referring to different memory blocks so they are completely separated.

Also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116226/why-does-updating-one-dictionary-object-affect-other), it might be useful for better clue.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually not a *stupid* question.

Most people like myself who have foundations built in languages like `C++` have a little difficulty with this at first when you start learning `Python`, or even `Java`.

Unlike C++, in Python, everything is returned as a reference.

So even if you are accessing a part of the object via another variable, you still are accessing the same part of the object.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773606/pass-by-reference-differences-in-c-vs-python) to get more context around this.